# Drupal 7- webform : how to reset the webform submission id (sid) to 0?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I am using webform and drupal7. during testing I had created many test submissions. Now I have cleared all the submissions and all my webform tables are empty. But if I create a new submission I still get the sid as 51 (ideally it should have been 1)

Can anyone let  me know how I can reset the sid value to 1?

Comment: Got it :)

I just had to do the following:

ALTER TABLE webform_submissions AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Thanks,

Comment: Cool. You can answer and accept your own question instead of posting in the comments so people can see the answer (and that it has been answered) if they search for the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it :) I just had to do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE webform_submissions AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Thanks,

Comment: What can be done to set the webform_submissions to begin at a certain number on a new system, such as say, 8000 instead of 1?